# WordPress questions (or is Drupal or a framework a better option?). User-contributed site for concert listings

Tags: wordpress, web

I'm making a website for video game music concerts. It is user-contributed, which means that anyone can input information about new concerts or modify existing ones. Editors can revert changes. User's would probably be divided into four groups: unregistered users, registered users, editors, admins.

The site will be on a subdomain of http://vgmdb.net/, which is site for video game music albums. Please take a look at that site and imagine my site being similar, but simpler. I'm a beginner programmer with only little experience of WordPress, Drupal, PHP and MySQL. Some people suggested to use a framework instead of a CMS. But I like WordPress the most and would prefer to use that.

- Can WordPress handle these things easily?

  1. Advanced search functions.

     - The concerts would be linked to specific games, artists, venues, cities, countries, genres, dates etc. in the style of VGMdb's advanced search
  2. User profiles with information about

     - what concerts they have been to ("went to this concert" -button on concerts)
     - what ratings they gave to concerts (5-star rating button on concerts)
  3. Image galleries for each concert

     - for scans of pamphlets and other stuff given at the concert
     - users upload this stuff (just like they modify and add information)
  4. Users can add or modify information about concerts

     - in an easy way in the style of http://vgmdb.net/album/new

Answer (score 0):

Of course it can be done in WordPress. But it wouldn't recommend it.
The biggest problem is that you want unregistered visitors to do these things. WP is good at managing content. But not if it is user generated.
It will end up unstable and totally user unfriendly.

I don't know if Drupal would be better.
I'd recommend learning [Zend framework](http://www.zendframework.com/) or [Symphony](http://www.symfony-project.org/) first.
You say you are a beginner, the hard truth is;
This is probably to big for you, and whatever you end using you will have to learn a lot more.